# Как сосчитать ссылки на объект c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне необходимо подсчитать ссылки на объект, и если осталась только 1, то удалить его. Дело в том, что все объекты хранятся в словаре:

```
Dictionary<int, object> objArray = new Dictionary<int, object>();

public void Destruct(int o)
{
    object obj = objArray[o];
    if(count_ref(obj) == 1)
        ...
}
```

Comment: Зачем? А если ктото получит ссылку на обхект и потом её 100 раз скопирует, как вы узнаете об этом?

Comment: Никто ее не получит и не скопирует, надо лишь посчитать ссылки. Это возможно?

Comment: Если никто не получит ссылку, то считать нечего - ссылок ноль. А вообще я слабо представляю, как посчитать существующие ссылки на объект и зачем бы это было бы нужно.

Comment: если вам надо только по словарю пробежать, что будет что то вроде `if (objArray.Values.Where(v=>object.ReferenceEquals(v,obj)).Count() == 1)`

Comment: Причем здесь словарь? Мне надо сосчитать ссылки на объект (будет ли он удален сборщиком мусора).

Comment: Создайте свой класс словаря, с подсчетом ссылок.

Comment: Скорее всего, я непонятно описал задачу. Одна ссылка на объект должна быть в этом словаре. У объекта могут быть и другие в абсолютно других местах. И нужно вот это все сосчитать. Мне нужно использовать какие-то приватные методы GC?

Comment: вы вообще какую задачу этим решаете? Чего хотите добиться?

Comment: Сложно объяснить, интерпретатор делаю. Есть вообще возможность подсчета ссылок?

Comment: Если и есть, то мне о такой неизвестно. Да и смысла это не имеет. Например, у вас могут быть 2 объекта, которые ссылаются друг на друга, но на них больше никто не ссылается. Формально на такие объекты по одной ссылке, но GC их уничтожит.  GC вообще скорее всего тоже не считает количество ссылок, GC интересна только достижимость объекта от корней, то есть GC интересно только ноль ссылок или не ноль от корня (наличие пути на объект от корня).

Comment: Я раньше использовал WeakReference для выполнения этой задачи (записать объект в WR, удалить объект из словаря, вызвать GC.Collect, потом, если WR содержит объект, добавить его в словарь заново). Но теперь по неизвестной причине со вчерашнего дня в .net 4.5 сборщик мусора утратил возможность очищать WR (код отсюда stackoverrun.com/ru/q/331648 возвращает true в обоих случаях). Как такое возможно?